# запись datetime в xls файл

Tags: c#

Читаю из базы MSSQl данные

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "rPSAlertTB");
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] = encoding(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
        if (j == ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 3 || j == ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 4)
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] = (DateTime)((DateTime)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j]).AddHours(3);
        if (j == ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 2)
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j] = "0." + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
}
```

и с помощью Microsoft.office.interop.excel записываю в xls

```
excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
excelWorkSheet = (Excel2.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets[1];
string ff = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= dsf.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= dsf.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (j == dsf.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 2 || j == dsf.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 3)
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToDateTime(dsf.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1][j - 1]);
        else
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, j + 1] = dsf.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1][j - 1];
    }
}
```

Потом когда читаю из этого файла, те столбцы которые должны быть datetime читаются как числа, что только не пробовал. Может надо как то тип данных указывать при записи? Подскажите направление!

Answer (score 1):

Можно указать любой формат даты если писать ее в ячейку как строку
В данном случае
Convert.ToDateTime(dsf.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1][j - 1]).ToString("{format}");
где {format} - [необходимый формат даты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать формат данных в столбце

```
var rg = (Excel.Range) excelWorkSheet.Cells[1,1];
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY";
```

Answer (score 0):

Конвертирование в строку определённого формата результат даёт, данные отображаются нормально (почемуто сработало только так "ДД.мм.гггг ч:мм", нашёл в формате ячейки excel ) , но мне потом ещё нужно считывать оттуда данные, а считывается почемуто всё равно double
Ничего не помогло пока на других ветках нашёл вот это
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ad4d8d6.aspx